# Continuously run loop while running program on Arduino?

Tags: loops, arduino

I have a question about running loops in Arduino. I've programmed an Arduino so that it slowly fades in LEDs and I'd like to add an LED that blinks while the program is running. I could change the whole program and put the LED blinking between all the lines, but I was wondering if there was a way it could be done seperately? Would it be possible to run a loop under *void setup()*, or to run a loop, and then move on to the next loop, while continuing to run the first loop?

The blinking light is of course not really important, but I was just curious if it could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the msTimer2 library for this purpose.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MsTimer2

An example of its use can also be found in a recent discussion in the German Arduino Forum here:

http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=cf3a483ed1812def070ebeaae09691c3&topic=146086.msg1100336#msg1100336

You do not need to understand German. Just take the code and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. The most elegant solution would be to set up a timer independently of the main run loop, and use its interrupt handler vector to turn the LED on and off. This way you can control the frequency of the blinking precisely, and you don't have to worry about how fast or slow the main loop is (that can change quite a bit if you add or remove computationally expensive code over time).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two or more independent loops run simultaneously, but you can achieve the same effect with something like this:

```
void do_stuff_0 ();
void do_stuff_1 ();

unsigned long last_millis_0 = 0;
unsigned long last_millis_1 = 0;

const unsigned long delay_0 = ...;
const unsigned long delay_1 = ...;

void loop ()
{
  now = millis();

  if ((now - last_millis_0) >= delay_0) {
    last_millis_0 = now;
    do_stuff_0 ();
  }
  if ((now - last_millis_1) >= delay_1) {
    last_millis_1 = now;
    do_stuff_1 ();
  }
  ...
}
```

This is just for illustration, you'll most likely want to use a library that abstracts this, like [metro](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/metro).